# eclipse 2023-09 for EE unable to set JPA and EJB Facet version

Tags: eclipse, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb

I started a ejb project and want to use Persistence 3.1 and Enterprise Beans 4.0. Maven loaded the jars, I added the maven dependancies to the libraries, but I'm still unable to select something greater JPA 2.2 or EJB 3.2. My Java version is 21.

What do I have to do, to get a JakartaEE10-EJB-Project in eclipse?

Comment: Basically, upgrade Eclipse. Or if you're already using latest then wait for next version to be released. If necessary push them by posting feature requests at their issue tracker or commenting/voting existing ones. Or switch to a different IDE or even plain notepad/xed. Technically speaking this is _not_ a JEE/JPA/EJB programming related problem but a software/editor/tooling related problem. By the way, are you familiar with superuser.com? That's basically stackoverflow.com but then for software product end users (like you with Eclipse) rather than for programming problems ;)

Comment: I totally agree with you, I guess, this is a eclipse or "not yet pressed the right button"-problem. Thanks, I will also try superuser.com.

Comment: I tried superuser.com, but they moved the question to stackoverflow.com: "This question was migrated from Super User because it can be answered on Stack Overflow. "